# Rendering HTML edited by TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, tinymce-4, materialize

I'm using the [tinymce editor](http://www.tinymce.com/) in a web page. When the user clicks the **save** button after editing, I'm getting the content from the editor and set them in a div as html ([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/49rzqgwn/)).

The problem is the content shown after saving is different from how it shows in the editor.
[image]

The content at the top of the image (edit view) and the bottom of the image (how user sees after editing) should be the same.

The reason for this is the two parts using different css. Anybody knows a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call TinyMCE you can specify the CSS it should use.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector:'textarea',
  content_css: '/css/style.css'
});
```

Docs at http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css

Edit in response to comment

In your CSS file you can set specify styles for TinyMCE as below:

```
#tinymce ul {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

Comment: I tried it. http://jsfiddle.net/49rzqgwn/1/ 
But then some functionality of the editor get affected. In this case the bullets are not working properly as the "  list-style-type" for "ul" is none in the site css.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the content.css file in the themes folder of tinymce to match what's displayed on your front end site.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css

Comment: I tried it. jsfiddle.net/49rzqgwn/1 But then some functionality of the editor get affected. In this case the bullets are not working properly as the " list-style-type" for "ul" is none in the site css.

Comment: So is the actual problem that the styles in the editor and on your site are different, or that bullet points are showing in the editor and not on your site?

Comment: The link to the CSS that you included in that fiddle is setting the list style type to none, is that the stylesheet you're using on your front end site?

Comment: I want to make the editor and the site similar without breaking any functionality of the editor. Ya. It sets the list style type to none. I'm using this style sheet in my site. That style sheet belongs to google's materializecss framework.. http://www.materializecss.com @DarkHippo